# Proving the maximum of $x+2y-3z$ exists

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima

I am trying to prove that maximum of $x+2y-3z$ (where $x,y,z$ are real numbers) exists under these two consitions:

$x^2-3xy+z^2 \le 5$

and

$4x^2-2xy + y^2 +4xz +10z^2 = 100$

I have spent some time on this question but find it hard. May I please ask for a solution or some idea and hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $4x^2 - 2xy + 4xz + 10z^2 = 100$ is an ellipsoid, which is  closed surface. The region of intersection of the constraints must be closed and bounded.  (You still have to show that they actually do intersect)  The objective function is continuous. And a continuous function evaluated over a closed and bounded domain has a maximum and a minimum.

Comment: one point the ellipsoid and the inequality have in common is (0,10,0)